# No loader is configured for ".node"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, npm

I am trying to use `Fabric.js` in my Angular project for `Canvas` management, and while the build is running this throw me this error. I am using Angular 17 for more references
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROo8X.png)

I installed the `node-loader` in npm but it does not work and I'm trying to use github info about that error but is rather few and unspecific.

Comment: Don't show pictures of text, [show the text itself](/help/how-to-ask). That said: did you delete the `node_modules` dir before running `npm install`?

Comment: Mike, yes, I did, but the error persists

Comment: Then please show the full error. And not as a picture, copy-paste the text, and put it in your post with code formatting.